# Hide header and footer when printing from Internet Explorer using Javascript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, printing

When I print a webpage from Internet Explorer it will automatically add a header and footer including the website title, URL, date, and page number.

Is it possible to hide the header and footer programatically using Javascript or CSS?

Requirements:

- works in IE 6 (no other browser support necessary as its for an Intranet)
- may use ActiveX, Java Applet, Javascript, CSS
- preferably not something that the user needs to install (eg. http://www.meadroid.com/scriptx). feel free to list other third party available plug-ins though as I think this may be the only option
- don't require the user to manually update their browser settings
- don't render the pages as PDF or Word document or any other format
- don't write to the registry (security prevents this)

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your print options you can disable this. The only way to do it programatically is with an activeX control which writes to the registry or a script block which is written in VB. The settings for your print options are stored in the registry. The user would have to allow your script to access the registry which most people wouldnt because of security.

If you want to control page content, you can use a css print stylesheet.

Edit: There are 3rd party active x controls which can programatically print for you, but once again, the user would have to choose to download and install it.

Comment: Got any more info on the activeX, registry locations or script block?

Comment: In IE8, headers and footers can be emptied in "File -> Page Setup"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not control it with javascript.
In my opinion, there is only option to use ActiveX in IE.
I am still looking for the answer.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I do some googling and everybody said: "Can't remove them!" except using ActiveX and 3rd party plugins.

I wonder why some reporting controls (Telerik Reporting, DevX,...) can hide Header & Footer without using ActiveX or plugins! Are they print the page in another ways? What way?

Comment: Telerik Reporting sends the data for printing as PDF and somehow launches PDF reader's (also an Active X/3rd party component) print feature.

Answer (score -6):

You can use a print stylesheet to change the layout of your page when it is being printed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #screen {}
            #print {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <style type="text/css" media="print">
            #screen {
                display: none;
            }
            #print {}           
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="screen">You'll see me in your browser!</div>
        <div id="print">But you will only see me when you print!</div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The question refers to hiding the page header and footer that are added onto the page when you print. They can't be hidden by CSS.

Comment: D'oh, someone clearly didn't read the entire question properly lol